# Converting xlsx to csv doesnt work for a specific file but does work for every other files

Tags: c#, csv

This is the method I'm using:

```
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yuanwang200409/how-to-convert-xls-file-into-csv-file-in-C-Sharp/
```

And it works for every other file, but for this one file it just gets one column even though it has six columns. The file is xlsx (Excell 2007). But I don't think it's the problem.

When I'm converting the file manually, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the excell file;s first row didn't have titles. I don't know why, but once I added an extra row for titles - it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy to debug.  The crux of the problem is somewhere in this code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    string rowString = "";
    for (int y = 0; y < dt.Columns.Count; y++)
    {
        rowString += "\"" + dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() + "\",";
    }
    wrtr.WriteLine(rowString);
}
```

I would step though and find out what the value of `rowString` looks like at each pass.  Is the `dt.Columns.Count` call coming back with a value of 1?  Open the `dt` in the debugger window and look at it in there.  Does it have multiple columns? Etc. etc.  You should be able to pick apart what these loops are doing and find the problem.

Let us know what you find.

Comment: dt.Columns.Count equals 1. The rowString  has the value of the second column. I know how to debug. I needed a solution.

Comment: So, you are saying that the data table only returns ONE column?  Is your question: "Why is the `OleDbCommand` `SELECT` only returning one column?"

Comment: Yes, why does it return one column and how to fix it?